# Spring-XD M7 version issue xd-admin is not running

Tags: spring-xd

When I tried to start xd-admin in M7 version, it failed with below error. Some where I read, we need to start x-container first and then start xd-admin. This also I tried, but same results.

Please confirm and help, is that zookeeper issue or am I missing some thing.

23:45:02,631 ERROR main server.AdminServerApplication:113 - Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.xd.dirt.plugins.job.DistributedJobService#0' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring-xd/batch/batch.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jobExecutionDao' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobExecutionDao' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring-xd/batch/batch.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not inspect meta data for database type.  You have to supply it explicitly.

Comment: Hi, Could some one help me please???

Comment: update to the newest version.   Also it's probably an issue in the servers.yml you need to setup a database jdbc properties there.  what database are you trying?